# How to add and remove UIToolbaritems programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add and remove the items on UIToolbar at runtime. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [setItems:animated](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIToolbar/setItems:animated:).  You pass in an area of items you want to display.  So you may have a bunch of button bar items in the NSArray.  You would just reset the array minus the items you want to remove to get rid of an icon.